# Return quickest times for a user in mysql leaderboard

Tags: mysql

I have a challenges table and a user table, and I want to return the minimum time for each user for a specific challenge (I'm building a leaderboard of fastest times)

So, I have:

```
user_id, username
1, rita
2, sue
3, bob

challenge_id, user_id, time
1, 1, 10
1, 1, 20
2, 1, 5
1, 2, 5
1, 3, 30
1, 3, 50
```

And I want the mySQL to return the results for challenge 1:

```
sue, 5
rita, 10
bob, 30
```

I've been fumbling around with this, I feel it's almost correct, but it only returns a single result, not the full set:

```
SELECT u.user_id, username, ac.quickest_time AS intScore 
FROM users u
JOIN 
(
    SELECT user_id, MIN(time_taken) AS quickest_time 
    FROM accepted_challenges 
    WHERE 
    challenges_id = 1
) ac ON ac.user_id = u.user_id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: **This is not a coding service!** What have you tried so far, and what's the issue with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT username, MIN(time)
FROM MyTable1 m1 INNER JOIN MyTable2 m2
ON m1.user_id = m2.user_id
WHERE m2.challenge_id = 1
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: Whhooa, I was way off! Cheers.